# struts.xml not well performed?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2

or, at least, I think the problem is in it...
In the first line below, the log says the stream is not null
in the second says, at the beginning of error stack trace, is null:

```
01/02 07:30:07| INFO [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (BillAction.java:704) - completeExport() - inputStream=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@11d1921
01/02 07:30:07| ERROR [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (CommonsLogger.java:34) - Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified f
or this action.
01/02 07:30:07| ERROR [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (CommonsLogger.java:38) - Exception occurred during processing request: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Chec
k the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
etc... etc...
```

This is the code that produces this kind of result:

Struts.xml

```
<action name="exportExcelBill" 
    class="it.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
    method="exportBillToExcel">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
    <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">jsp/common/intermeanExcel.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="completeExport" 
    class="it.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
    method="completeExport">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
    <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${reportFile}"</param>
        <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

exportBillToExcel():

```
public String exportBillToExcel() {
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet(categ);
    try {

    ... etc. body of the method ... etc...

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
===>    session.put("tmpstream", inputStream);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

intermeanExcel.jsp:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <%@ include file="./warningwait.jsp" %>

     <script> 
         $(document).ready(function() {
                                        closeBoxWait(previous_boxWait);
                                        window.location = '<s:url namespace="/" action="completeExport"/>';
                                    }); 
    </script>   
</body>
```

completeExport():

```
public String completeExport() {
    inputStream = (InputStream)session.get("tmpstream");
    logger.info("completeExport() - inputStream="+inputStream);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and naturally in the class are present the inputStream declaration and get and set methods.

where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your `getInputStream()` method? Maybe there is some mistake. You don't need a `setInputStream()` method for the file download.

BTW: the "parking" of the input stream in the session is a bit awkward. I'm not sure if this works. I guess you have to create the inputStream in the `completeExport()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the result type as stream in struts.xml

```
<action name="exportExcelBill" 
    class="it.colmenjv.dlq.actions.BillAction"
    method="exportBillToExcel">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
    <result type = "stream">
        <param name="inputName">tmpstream</param>
    </result>
    <result name="login">timeout.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">jsp/common/intermeanExcel.jsp</result>
</action>
```

No need to put the tmpstream object into session in java class. Since we have defined tmpstream within result, it would be available in jsp to access.